# Error in tikz table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, errors

In this `tikzpicture`, I have the following message of error:

`Missing number, treated as zero. ...$ /1,}{$-\infty$ , $0$ , $4$ , $+\infty$}`

What is the problem?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $|x|$ /1,$|x-4|$ /1,}                   
   {$-\infty$ , $0$ , $4$ , $+\infty$}

\tkzTabLine{,-x,z,x,t,x,}

\tkzTabLine{,4-x,t,4-x,z,x-4,}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and with `\end{document}` on the end!

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong comma at the end of the `\tkzTabInit` description of the rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $|x|$ /1,$|x-4|$ /1}% You have a wrong final comma here                   
    {$-\infty$ , $0$ , $4$ , $+\infty$}

\tkzTabLine{,-x,z,x,t,x,}

\tkzTabLine{,4-x,t,4-x,z,x-4,}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]